# How to print out only the script name?

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
[username@notebook ~]$ cat foo.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo "$0"
[username@notebook ~]$ ./foo.sh
./foo.sh
[username@notebook ~]$
```

**Question**: How can I output the "foo.sh"? No matter how was it executed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [`basename`](http://man.cx/basename):

```
#!/bin/bash

basename -- "$0"
```

If you want to assign it to a variable, you'd do:

```
my_name=$(basename -- "$0")
```

Answer (score 14):

POSIXly, you only need [Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

```
#!/bin/bash

printf '%s\n' "${0##*/}"
```