# getting current script location in bash (like python __file__ variable)

Tags: bash, shell-script

How can I get the full filename of a script in bash?
(Similar to python's `__file__` variable)

something like

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# my-script.sh

# would evaluate to /dir/my-script.sh
thisfile=$(get-name-for-this-script)

# Do something with some other local file 
cp $(dirname $thisfile)/something.txt .
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print out only the script name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198925/how-to-print-out-only-the-script-name)

Comment: @Quasímodo `$0` isn't quite the same as Python's `__file__`: `$0` doesn't track scripts included with `.`.

Comment: but the . will tell me that the current working directory is where it's running from right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any sh-like shell, `$0` is the path to the executing script. This is documented for bash under [special parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters). This can be a relative path, in which case it's relative to the current directory when the shell started.

Note that `$0` does not change when a script executes another script with `.` or `source`. A closer analog to Python's `__file__`, which indicates which file contains the currently executing code, is [`$BASH_SOURCE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fSOURCE). The manual isn't very clear on that topic, but `$BASH_SOURCE` is the name of the file containing the currently executing line, even for code that isn't in a function. Like `$0`, `$BASH_SOURCE` can be a relative path: it's whatever was passed to the `.` builtin, and won't change if the shell runs subsequent `cd` commands.

Comment: How could I forget that the first argument is the filename...

Comment: Note: You should use `$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")` to get the dirname containing the script, to handle the situation where the script name is itself a symlink.

Comment: @jrw32982supportsMonica Only if you want the directory containing the actual script file. I don't see why you'd prefer that to the directory containing the symlink.

Comment: You would use the actual directory containing the script file to find other files installed alongside it, either in the same directory or in sibling directories relative to that directory.  I'm not sure why you would want the directory containing a symlink to the script.  Since the OP's code found the containing directory of the script, I thought I should demonstrate that using just `dirname` will not necessarily find the actual containing directory. The way I mentioned is non-portable but common nowadays.  I don't know of a short, POSIX way.

Answer (score 0):

Most answers either don't handle files which are symlinked via a relative path, aren't one-liners or don't handle BSD (Mac).  A solution which does all three is:

```
HERE=$(cd "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")"; cd -P "$(dirname "$(readlink "$BASH_SOURCE" || echo .)")"; pwd)
```

First, cd to bash's conception of the script's directory.  Then readlink the file to see if it is a symlink (relative or otherwise), and if so, cd to that directory.  If not, cd to the current directory (necessary to keep things a one-liner).  Then echo the current directory via `pwd`.

You could add `--` to the arguments of cd and readlink to avoid issues of directories named like options, but I don't bother for most purposes.

You can see the full explanation with illustrations here (this is my site):

https://www.binaryphile.com/bash/2020/01/12/determining-the-location-of-your-script-in-bash.html

Comment: If you're linking to your own site, please note that or it will be considered spam